# Can I configure AWS RDS to only stream INSERT operations to AWS DMS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, logical-replication, aws-dms

My requirement is to stream only INSERTs on a specific table in my db to a Kinesis data stream.

I have configured this pipeline in my AWS environment:

```
RDS Postgres 13 -> DMS (Database Migration Service) -> KDS (Kinesis Data Stream)
```

This setup works correctly but it processes all changes, even UPDATEs and DELETEs, on my source table.

What I've tried:

- Looking for config options in the Postgres logical decoding plugin. DMS uses the `test_decoding` PG plugin which does not accept options to include/exclude data changes by operation type.
- Looking at the DMS selection and filtering rules. Still didn't see anything that might help.

Of course I could simply ignore records originated from non-INSERT operations in my Kinesis consumer, but this doesn't look like a cost-efficient implementation.

Is there any way to meet my requirements using these AWS services (RDS -> DMS -> Kinesis)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well DMS does not have this capability .

If you want only INSERT to be send to Kinesis in that case you can have a lambda function on every INSERT of RDS .
Lambda function can be configured as trigger for INSERT .

You can invoke lambda only for INSERT and write to Kinesis directly .

Cost wise also this will be less .
In DMS you are paying for Replication instance even when not in use .

For detailed reference  [Stream changes from Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL using Amazon Kinesis Data Streams and AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/stream-changes-from-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-using-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-and-aws-lambda/)